# How do I set the default decimal number separator in Python?

Tags: c#, python, python-3.x, parsing, floating-point

I am working on two applications, one running in C#/.NET and the other with the Python 3 interpreter targeting Windows 10 only. The two applications communicate with each other using a local network socket for IPC (Inter-Process-Communication).

Since both Windows machines might have different settings for the decimal number separation (comma or point), making and parsing floating points becomes a nightmare. For example the first machines interprets the floating point as `1.23` and the other machines expects `1,23` which leads to a program error.

In the past, I used the following lines to set the default separator to "." for the current process in C#/.NET:

```
CultureInfo customCulture = (CultureInfo)Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.Clone();
customCulture.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator = ".";
CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture = customCulture;
```

Is there something similar for Python in order to get rid of comma/point floating point parsing issue?

Comment: Why are you passing it as a string, and not as a number?

Comment: When working with TCP/IP network sockets there's only a byte network stream. The receiving process does not know out-of-the-box how to interpret what the other process has sent. Implementing the protocol is the responsability of the application developer and interpreting the floating point numbers depend on the operating system settings (if not parsing yourself).

Comment: But why should the byte network stream hinder you in sending a number as bytes? - as a little example see this: https://dotnetfiddle.net/Sh5qBl - I don't know how to read a Byte Array in python and get a number of it, but maybe this information helps you out anyway

Comment: Is this actually a problem? It seems to me that python always formats numbers with a `.` as radix separator unless you explicitly use format code `n` (which is buggy, at least in the versions of Python I've used.)